# i want to add credentials to window.open(url) in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8, angular4-httpclient

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZiSd.png)

i am having this issue in window.open
below is code

```
  repourl:any='http://192.168.1.104/....'
 ngOnInit() {
 var params = {
  Username: 'd2kuser',
  Password: '****'};window.open(this.repourl);
```

Is there any way i can pass credential with widow open.

Comment: Have you tried using the format 'user:password@url' in your first line? If it's through Basic Authentication then that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    form = document.createElement("form");
   form.action = url;
   form.method = verb;
   form.target = target || "_blank";
   if (_data) {
       var data = _data.split("&")
       for (var key = 0; key < data.length; key++) {
           var input = document.createElement("textarea");
           input.name = data[key].split("=")[0];
           input.value = data[key].split("=")[1];
           form.appendChild(input);
       }
   }
   form.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.submit();
```

> use different approach for same , submitted form action

Answer (score 0):

Add Username and Password as queryparams in URL. It will work.